# jQuery: inline onclick

Tags: jquery

I've got a INPUT that has an onclick event in it

```
<input type="radio" name="shipment" value="1" onclick="if (this.checked) $('#total').html(2);" style="display: none; ">
```

and A element

```
<a class="shipment">shipment</a>
```

and jquery code

```
$('.shipment').live('click', function () {
   $(this).prev('input[type="radio"]').click(); // input field is checked, but onclick not working
}
```

how to call online script in input ?

Comment: I guess a class/id attribute is missing from your input control..

Comment: Use: `onclick="if (this.checked) document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '2';" style="display: none;"`and `on('click')`

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the following in your a's click handler:

```
$('.shipment').live('click', function () {
   $(this).prev('input[type="radio"]').trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use .live() instead of it use .on()

```
$(document).on('click','.shipment',function () {
   $(this).prev('input[type="radio"]').click(); 
});
```

Comment: why should you never use .live()?

Comment: because live is slow , don't maintain chainability and many more reasons

Comment: Its not like you should 'never' use live.....but yes,live has been deprecated now..

Comment: @Misam no i think 'never' is ok

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell read http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/#.UA6TEGUQZYE